# Cant access column of a record in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Cartridge model with cartridge_name:

```
t.string   "cartridge_name", null: false
```

I perform query on it:

```
@cartridge = Cartridge.where('cartridge_name=?', "#{value[:cartridge_id]}")
```

It returns an object:

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Cartridge id: 1, cartridge_name: "HP laserjet 3000", note: "", created_at: "2015-04-14 08:05:37", updated_at: "2015-04-14 08:05:37">]>
```

But when i try to access @cartridge.id or @cartridge.cartridge_name
it return an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `cartridge_name' for #<Cartridge::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbd77bf38f8>
```

I have no idea why is it like that. What can cause that error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`where` returns a collection containing your relations. You need to do something like this to get the actual `Cartridge`:

```
@cartridge = Cartridge.where('cartridge_name=?', "#{value[:cartridge_id]}").first
```

or:

```
@cartridge = Cartridge.find_by(cartridge_name: value[:cartridge_id])
```